# <p:graphicImage> muestra la misma imagen siempre

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, rest, maven

Tengo un WS(Rest) que retorna un objeto de tipo `SERVIDOR`y depende de un Id que le pase.

```
@GET
@Path("emps")
@Produces("application/xml")
public List <SERVIDOR> sendFoto(@QueryParam("a") String a)
```

y desde otra aplicación, obtengo ese objeto, pero cuando quiero mostrar la foto de tipo `byte[]`, muestra siempre la misma foto, he comprobado que el objeto si cambia cuando le envío otro ID.

Método `getRestServidor()`:

```
      GenericType<List<SERVIDOR>> generic = new GenericType<List<SERVIDOR>>() {};
      System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
      this.setEmployee(response.getEntity(generic));
      for(SERVIDOR c:this.getEmployee()){
          this.setIs(new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[]) c.getNUEVA_FOTO()));
          this.setMyImage(new DefaultStreamedContent(this.getIs(), "image/png"));
      }
```

Pagina JSF:

```
 /*code*/
<p:commandButton value="Enviar" actionListener="#{paramReportController.checkBiometrico}" styleClass="ui-priority-primary"  update=":f1:growl2 :f1:pn1 :f1:png1 :f1:pn2"/>
        <div class="grid-example col s12 m6">
           <p:panel id="pn2">
              <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:graphicImage value="#{paramReportController.myImage}"    alt="sin imagen" id="pic1" style="width:200px;width:200px">
                </p:graphicImage>
             </p:panelGrid>
          </p:panel>
/*code*/
```

También debo mencionar que para llegar al método `getRestServidor()`, primero pasa por un método llamado `checkBiometrico()` y éste llama al `getRestServidor()`.

Espero que puedan ayudarme!! 
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si alguien se encuentra con el mismo problema la solución es no usar caché en el componente grafico.

```
<p:graphicImage .... cache="false"/>
```

Comment: Detalla mejor tu respuesta